# Java Double vs double: class type vs primitive type

Tags: java, performance, class, double, primitive

I was curious to what the performance differences between Java's class and primitive type for double were. So I created a little benchmark and found the class type to be 3x-7x slower than the primitive type. (3x on local machine OSX, 7x on ideone)

Here is the test:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long bigDTime, littleDTime;

        {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            Double d = 0.0;
            for (Double i = 0.0; i < 1432143.341; i += 0.1) {
                d += i;
            }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            bigDTime = end - start;
            System.out.println(bigDTime);
        }

        {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            double d = 0.0;
            for (double i = 0.0; i < 1432143.341; i += 0.1) {
                d += i;
            }
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            littleDTime = end - start;
            System.out.println(littleDTime);
        }

        System.out.println("D/d = " + (bigDTime / littleDTime));
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/fDizDu

So why is the Double type so much slower? Why is it even implemented to allow mathematical operators?

Comment: It is slow due to the need to box and unbox. This is expected behavior.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That makes sense but it still seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: It is a lot of overhead. And for that reason you should avoid use of primitive wrapper types in time critical code.

Comment: The cost is higher for multi-threaded programs.  This is because using `Double` is literally filling the caches with garbage, which will slow down other threads in most cases.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> So why is the Double type so much slower?

Because the value is wrapped inside an object which needs allocation, deallocation, memory management plus getters and setters

> Why is it even implemented to allow mathematical operators?

Because autobox is meant to allow you to use such wrappers without worrying about the fact that they are not plain values. Would you prefer not being able to have an `ArrayList<Double>`? Performance is **not always** necessary and a drop of 3x-7x of performance according to situations maybe acceptable. Optimization is a requirement which is not always present.

This is true in every situation, using a `LinkedList` to random access elements could be overkill but this doesn't mean that `LinkedList` shouldn't be implemented at all. This neither means that using a linked list for few random accesses could interfere with performance so much.

**A final note**: you should let the VM warm up before benchmarking such things.

Answer (score 8):

You wouldn't normally use `Double`, `Integer`, etc. (Occasionally `Integer` etc. can be useful to store an 'optional' value - you might want it to be `null` sometimes. This is less likely with `Double` because `NaN` is available for those.)

The reason `Double` exists is as follows. Java has two main types of value: objects (essentially like C/C++ pointers without the arithmetic), and primitive values (e.g. `double`). Classes like `ArrayList` can be defined to accept any `Object`, which allows users to store `String`, `File` or whatever they like in one - but primitive values like `double` are not covered by such a definition. So classes like `Double` exist to make it easier for classes like `ArrayList` to store `double`s, without requiring the authors of `ArrayList` to create special versions for all the primitive types.

Answer (score 4):

`Double` is a boxed `double`. Thus in general the compiled code has to check the `Double` for null before doing anything with it. This is of course slower than doing nothing.

`Double` (and other boxed versions of the primitives) is useful because it's an `Object`. This allows you to pass it around to functions that would take an `Object`, and cast it back to `Double` somewhere else. More usefully, it allows for generic types to contain it: A generic type cannot contain `double` or any other primitive, but it can contain a `Double`.