# Room error in query columns return

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I've seen this issue [room-error-the-columns-returned-by-the-query-does-not-have-the-fields-fieldname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967722/room-error-the-columns-returned-by-the-query-does-not-have-the-fields-fieldname) but I cant apply it to my own error.

This is my `Movie` class

```
    @Entity
    public class Movie {

        @PrimaryKey
        @NonNull
        public String id;

        @ColumnInfo
        public String name;

        @ColumnInfo
        public String title;
    }
```

This is my `UpcomingMovies` class

```
@Entity(
        foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
                entity = Movie.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "movieId")
        },
        indices = @Index("movieId")
)
@TypeConverters(MovieConverter.class)
public class UpcomingMovies {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo
    public int movieId;

    @ColumnInfo
    public Movie movie;
}
```

The query I'm trying to run, which I want to get a List of movies

```
@Query("Select movie from UpcomingMovies")
LiveData<List<Movie>> loadUpcomingMovies();
```

And the specific error I'm getting

> error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] in *.Model.POJOs.Movie even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [movie]

What've I missed here ?

Edit: Added `MovieConverter`

```
public class MovieConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public String movieToString(Movie movie) {
        return new Gson().toJson(movie);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public Movie stringToMovie(String src) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(src, Movie.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add MovieConverter.class code

Comment: @TomasJablonskis Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
@Query("Select * from UpcomingMovies")
LiveData<List<UpcomingMovies>> loadUpcomingMovies();
```

And have a GETTER method in your `UpcomingMovies` class:

```
public Movie getMovie() {
    return this.movie;
}
```

---

You can also get list of movies with this query:

```
@Query("Select * from Movie")
LiveData<List<Movie>> loadUpcomingMovies();
```

---

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks bro, the error went away, can you provide some explanation ? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Greggz The thing is, that you were trying to get a list of **Movie** objects, while **UpcomingMovies** only has one instance of it.

Comment: But can't I just return the list of movies from the Upcoming table ?

Comment: Hum.. I though every row would have a Movie

Comment: No. If I were you I would better of query Movie table with specific parameter in SQL query, to get specific list of Movies.

Comment: Well, you are correct, every row of UpcomingMovies has a Movie instance. But its the same as if you were getting just a simple Movie list from Movie table.

Comment: @Greggz Both queries that I provided above will return the same List of Movies, just that it will be wraped in UpcomingMovie class if using the first one.

Comment: @Greggz If you want to have List<Movie> while querying UpcomingMovies table, you should look into MANY:MANY table relasionships. You can look up the implementation [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a)

Comment: I see that, so if `Select * from UpcomingMovies` will return movies with their `movieId` , why `Select movie from UpcomingMovies` doesn't return every movie instance present in the table ?

Comment: Thanks! That was just what I was about to ask you, some documentation, cause clearly my knowledge is lacking.. Thank you so much! Cheers