# Error in Room Query to Return Subset of Columns

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I was playing with Room, where I couldn't find some solution to my queries.

Below is the data.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `first_name` TEXT,
    `last_name` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

**Table Data**

[image]

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    ..Getters & Setters..
}
```

**Query 1**

```
@Query("Select * from Employee")
List<Employee> getEmployees();
```

**Result**
Its successfull

**Query 2**

```
@Query("Select first_name, last_name from Employee")
List<Employee> getEmployees();
```

**Result**

> error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] in ***.Employee even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [first_name, last_name]

If I add `id` to above `Query 2`, it works.

Same goes, if we have a `Foreign Key` in the Table and we try to Query Subset of Columns, it throws Error. The Error goes when we add both `Primary Key` & `Foreign Key` Column in the Query.

**Question 1**
 Does that mean we have to always include `Primary Key` & `Foreign Key` 
 (if present) in a Query ?

**Question 2**
What actually happens under the hood that it throws such error ? Or Am I doing anything wrong ?

**Room Version**
1.1.1

Also, referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967722/room-error-the-columns-returned-by-the-query-does-not-have-the-fields-fieldname) but it doesn't solve my issue with Primary Keys.

Comment: Just guessing: "SELECT first_name FROM EMPLOYEE" can only yield a List<String>. If you insist on returning a List<Employee> the runtime will have to fill in some default values. But on the one hand a primary key column can not be filled with null, on the other hand the query result does not have the correct id for a specific first_name value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [room error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields fieldname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967722/room-error-the-columns-returned-by-the-query-does-not-have-the-fields-fieldname)

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: The link I have already referred before posting my question. That link tells about other fields value but mine is related to Primary Keys.

Comment: @0X0nosugar: Thanks, I got it know. :) I have edited my post. As, I need List of Employees with first_name and last_name without IDs. Only way I can think of now is, first I have to Query with ID and then create a wrapper to send without IDs.

Comment: @akashPatra I am also getting the same error for second Query. Once I add id field, it works fine but my requirement is to get only two columns. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ShubhamAnand: Create a another class like mentioned by Karan in the solution. In that class, only mention the two columns and room will automatically map it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To select data from multiple fields consider below example.

**From the docs**

> Room allows you to return any Java-based object from your queries as
>   long as the set of result columns can be mapped into the returned
>   object. For example, you can create the following plain old Java-based
>   object (POJO) to fetch the user's first name and last name:

```
public class NameTuple {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;
}
```

**Now, you can use this POJO in your query method:**

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user")
    public List<NameTuple> loadFullName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks fine. But, if my Query is "Select first_name, last_name from Employee" like this. I have updated in the post, as I need list of Employees.

Comment: @akashPatra: check from the docs https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#java

Comment: But with this my Query 1 will fail. I have to run both Query 1 and Query 2 using same Employee Class.

Comment: why it will fail? You will keep your employee class as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @karan's answer, the pojo can also be used to return named columns using **as** clause

For eg.

```
select sum(score) as total_score, sum(avg) as avg_score from mytable
```

where the pojo class column names will be total_score and avg_score respectively ..

Answer (score 0):

> I think you should include in
>           `@ColumnInfo(name = "id") 
>           @PrimaryKey
>            private int id;`
>
> because as per the error thrown there is no such column existing as id in your entity by the above query, first the column id is referred as match of the tables column id and then set a primary key via annotation

Comment: The `@ColumnInfo(name = "id")` doesn't add value to the code. As my variable name is same as column name.